# Compare folders and delete duplicates

Tags: powershell

I have a folder (dated with yesterday's date) on our R Drive for each day's reports.

These are copied over each morning from our J Drive, to which only some people have access. I do the copy with PowerShell but am fairly new to it, so have always been too scared to use MOVE instead of COPY, and to delete the originals from the J Drive. So I do that manually after ensuring the copy was successful.

What I want to do is: find all files (they are txt and ZIP) in the R Drive folder, that ALSO exist on the J Drive, and if their sizes are the same, delete the ones on the J Drive.

What is the best way of doing this? I'd prefer to not handle each file separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, here's an example of how I've done something similar in the past:

```
$one = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\test1
$two = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\test2

$matches = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $one  -DifferenceObject $two -Property Name,Length -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual)

foreach ($file in $matches)
{
    Remove-Item c:\temp\test2\$($file.Name)
}
```

I suspect you may want to add some logging to this, maybe even prompt for deletion if you're the extremely nervous type. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use MOVE.  It's as secure as using copy.

Comment: Some of the ZIPs are 2GB+. There are risks of power being cut while the move is taking place, etc. I know I might be unreasonable in my request, but I want to COPY, and then towards the end of the day have a cleanup script for the J Drive. I do not want to MOVE the files.

Comment: `Move` will not delete the file until it has successfully transferred.

Comment: Of course having just one, or only two copies is foolhardy too.  You must have a backup or two elsewhere.

Comment: I will keep that in mind - good to know, thanks. My question still remains the same - I would like a cleanup script which I'm going to run at the end of the day. There are other factors here why I do not want to delete the originals right after the copy/move.

Comment: Why not use ROBOCOPY or XXCOPY?  Either one will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you copy them all to the same folder then windows would want to put a (1) at the end of the dup files(if they have the same name)
and then you could run

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Your\Path*(1)*' | Remove-Item

just worked for me